# How To Drag And Drop the Items in Decending order using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

Hi Iam new to selenium,

In URL: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ with help of Mouse We need to sort the list. I tried this code but nothing happens any workaround in selenium how we can do this?

there are 7 items we need to sort data in descending order by mouse

I tried the below code but it's not working how can I achieve it

```
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/sortable/");

driver.switchTo().frame(0);

List<WebElement> lists = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortable']/li"));

Actions a = new Actions(driver);

for(int i=0;i<lists.size();++i){

WebElement element  = lists.get(i);

String text =  lists.get(i).getText();

String[] values = text.split(" ");

int number = Integer.valueOf(values[1]);
}

a.clickAndHold(lists.get(0)).dragAndDrop(lists.get(0), lists.get(6)).build().perform();
a.clickAndHold(lists.get(0)).moveToElement(lists.get(3)).release().build().perform();
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for(int i =dragAndDropElement.size();i>1;i--) {

```
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)["+i+"])"));
        
//Just collected all the destination location,          
        WebElement destination1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[1])"));
        WebElement destination2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[2])"));
        WebElement destination3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[3])"));
        WebElement destination4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[4])"));
        WebElement destination5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[5])"));
        WebElement destination6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[6])"));
        WebElement destination7 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[7])"));
        
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        
        if(element!=null) {
           
            action.dragAndDrop(destination1,element).perform();
             
            action.dragAndDrop(destination2,element).perform();
          
            
            action.dragAndDrop(destination3,element).perform();
           
            
            action.dragAndDrop(destination4,element).perform();
            
            
            action.dragAndDrop(destination5,element).perform();
           
            action.dragAndDrop(destination6,element).perform();
            
            
            action.dragAndDrop(destination7,element).perform();
            
            
            
             
            
            
            break;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with this solution, Further, you could enhance this as per your requirement and simplification. Anyway, I hope it will help you.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/sortable/");
    
    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
    
    List<WebElement> dragAndDropElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortable']/li"));
    System.out.println(dragAndDropElement.size());
    
    for(int i =1;i<dragAndDropElement.size();i++) {
        
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)["+i+"])"));
        
//Just collected all the destination location,          
        WebElement destination1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[1])"));
        WebElement destination2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[2])"));
        WebElement destination3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[3])"));
        WebElement destination4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[4])"));
        WebElement destination5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[5])"));
        WebElement destination6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[6])"));
        WebElement destination7 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//ul[@id='sortable']/li)[7])"));
        
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        
        if(element!=null) {
            
            action.dragAndDrop(destination7,element).perform();
            action.dragAndDrop(destination6,element).perform();
            action.dragAndDrop(destination5,element).perform();
            action.dragAndDrop(destination4,element).perform();
            action.dragAndDrop(destination3,element).perform();
            action.dragAndDrop(destination2,element).perform();
            action.dragAndDrop(destination1,element).perform();
            
            break;
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: @sumit goyal can you check with the given answer and let us know more on this?

Comment: Really Appreciate you again an indian helped :P Thanks man

Comment: @     Hi Manish I have written same code I can see in the question which I asked I modified your code the reverse way then its not working can you pls let me know the reason I have edited my code please check I just made few changes in for loop and the code you made why reverse way not works here ?

Comment: I have added code after //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: @sumitgoyal let me check it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
List<WebElement> lists = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortable']/li"));
// above list holds size of 7
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
WebElement lastEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Item " + lists.size() + "']"));
// I am picking last element as we have to sort in descending order. That means 1-7, 2-7, 3-7 etc..
// At last the order should be Item 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.
for(int i=1;i<=lists.size() - 1;++i) {
// Here, I don't want to drag last element i.e Item 7 as it will be on top at last. That is why I am not considering 7th element to drag
    WebElement elementToDrag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Item " + i + "']"));
    a.clickAndHold(elementToDrag).dragAndDrop(elementToDrag, lastEle).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Sreenivasulu thank you but this code is  not working.Pls help

Comment: yes sir can you pls check on ur machine some error like incorrect xpath

Comment: Updated the xpath.. can you try once

Comment: After adding  driver.switchTo.frame(0)  code is working but not doing the task which we want it tries to sort the data which i can see but its unable to do.could you pls have a look thnx